# Como configurar AutoMapper em um projeto WindowsForm?

Tags: c#, automapper

Como eu faço para configurar o [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) em uma aplicação Windows Forms App, sendo:

- Qual arquivo e devo configurar para carregar juntamente com a aplicação e que fique disponível?
- Como utilizar com um exemplo simples?

Comment: @alambique um exemplo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar o [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) em uma aplicação `Windows Forms`, *siga os seguintes passos*:

Instale o pacote via [NUGET](https://www.nuget.org)

> **PM>** `Install-Package AutoMapper`

Crie os modelos que devem ser utilizados em seu projeto:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class ClassD
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

e apos a instalação do pacote e as classes que serão utilizadas abra o arquivo `Program.cs` e crie dois métodos:

```
public static void InitializeAutoMapper()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Load());
}

public static Action<AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression> Load()
{
    return _ =>
    {
        _.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();
        _.CreateMap<ClassC, ClassD>();
        //_.CreateMap add mais configuração.
    };
}
```

Todas as classes a serem configuradas faça no método `Load()`, como está no exemplo e no `InitializeAutoMapper` será chamada as configurações, é uma forma de configuração que podem sofrer alterações (*isso é um exemplo*).

Para funcionar isso na sua aplicação, vai no método `Main` do `Program.cs` e adicione a linha `InitializeAutoMapper();` da seguinte forma:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    InitializeAutoMapper(); // adicionando para ficar global na sua app.
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);            
    Application.Run(new Form1());            
}
```

e com isso fica disponível em seu projeto. Um observação é que esse método deve ser chamado antes `Application.Run(new Form1());` se não essa configuração não será carregada corretamente.

***Código completo:***

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        InitializeAutoMapper(); // adicionando para ficar global na sua app.
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);            
        Application.Run(new Form1());            
    }

    public static void InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Load());
    }

    public static Action<AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression> Load()
    {
        return _ =>
        {
            _.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();
            _.CreateMap<ClassC, ClassD>();
            //_.CreateMap add mais configuração.
        };
    }
}
```

---

Para utilizar é fácil um exemplo bem simples seria:

```
var b = new ClassB
{
    Id = 10,
    Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};
var c = new ClassC
{
    Id = 10,
    Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
};

ClassA result0 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClassA>(b);
ClassD result1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClassD>(c);
```

***Nota:*** *isso é um exemplo bem simples para exemplifica o tutorial*.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)
- [Can Automapper be used in a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734659/can-automapper-be-used-in-a-console-application)
- [Para que serve o AutoMapper?](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2015/05/06/para-que-serve-o-automapper/)
- [.NET - Apresentando e usando o AutoMapper (mapeando propriedades de um objeto para outro)](http://www.macoratti.net/15/07/net_amap1.htm)