# Erro ao acessar a propriedade CreateMap do AutoMapper 6.2.2

Tags: c#, automapper

Estou praticando em um exemplo simples que achei na *net* sobre o assunto. Só que acredito que esteja em uma versão mais antiga do `AutoMapper` e por isso não consigo Acessar a propriedade `CreateMap` quando chamo a classe `Mapper`. Parece que mudou a maneira de se fazer o processo.

[image: prinscreen com um exemplo de cadificação com erro]

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string SobreNome { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaViewModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string SobreNome { get; set; }

    public string NomeCompleto
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Nome, SobreNome);
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pessoa = new Pessoa()
    {
        Nome = "João",
        SobreNome = "Silva"

    };

    var pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel()

    Mapper.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>();
    Mapper.Map(pessoa, pessoaViewModel);


    Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.Nome);
    Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.SobreNome);
    Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.NomeCompleto);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254282/como-configurar-automapper-em-um-projeto-windowsform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O CreateMap foi modificado do Mapper, tem diversas formas de utilizar, vou colocar a mais simples que resolve seu problema:
 (https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/issues/212)

Utilize:

```
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>();
        });
```

Ficaria assim:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa()
{
    Nome = "João",
    SobreNome = "Silva"
};

var pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel();

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>();
});

Mapper.Map(pessoa, pessoaViewModel);

Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.Nome);
Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.SobreNome);
Console.WriteLine(pessoaViewModel.NomeCompleto);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Obrigado Thiago! Funcionou 100%